# Prevent paragraph from being edited in a Word document using SDK 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml-sdk

I am using  `Open XML SDK` to add  a serial number to each document that the user will download.

This is the code:

```
public static void OpenAndAddTextToWordDocument(string filepath, string txt)
{
    // Open a WordprocessingDocument for editing using the filepath.
    WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true);

    // Assign a reference to the existing document body.
    Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

    // Add new text.
    Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());



    Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
    run.AppendChild(new Text(txt));

    DocumentWatermarkTest.AddWaterMark(wordprocessingDocument);

    // Close the handle explicitly.
    wordprocessingDocument.Close();
}
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strDoc = @"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\2138-1.doc";
    string strTxt = "Serial number: 23jl4hk52345h32jkl";
    OpenAndAddTextToWordDocument(strDoc, strTxt);
}
```

Now I need to prevent the user to delete the serial number when he opens the doc.

I read in the Open XML SDK 2.0 FAQ:

> Open XML SDK only support features to protect a document such as
>   preventing the sheet from being edited in UI

However, it does not explain how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a content place holder (tag) through Developer tab from microsoft word. In the properties of this tag you can restrict user for "Content cannot be edited" also "Content control cannot be deleted". Now you can access this Content Place Holder with its tag name programatically and can place your serial number inside.

Comment: i'd be very happy if you could provide some details. THanks for the reply

Comment: hmm. first of all are you familiar with Developer tab of microsoft word? it will give me some idea of from where to start explaining.

Comment: From your MS Word Ribbon go to Word Options and than under Popular tab select "Show Developer tab in the Ribbon". Now you can see Developer tab appearing on top of the word menu bar. Under developer tab turn Design Mode On. Here you can also find different type of content place holder (Rich Text, Text, Picture, ComboBox etc.). In your case Rich Text will serve the purpose. Just click on Rich Text and word will place this control where your curser is. Now select this tag and go to the properties which you can find just under the Design Mode button or by right clicking. Check the relevent box.

Comment: also not to foget giving a name to this tag so that you can access this tag programatically with its name and can place your serial number inside. Let me know if you also need code example of accessing this tag through C#.